# Is there an endomorphism $F$ and a vector $v$, such that $F$-invariant $span\{v, F(v), F^2(v), ...\}$ is decomposable

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V'$ is any vector space, can a vector $v' \in V'$ and an endormorphism $F: V' \rightarrow V'$ exist, such that the $F$-invariant subspace $U = span\{v',F(v'), F^2(v'), ...\}$ is decomposable into two other $F$-invariant subspaces $V,W$ with $U=V \oplus W$?

Intuitively I think that this is possible, but I can't think of a working example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $V = \def\R{\mathbf R}\R^2$, $F(x) = (x_1, -x_2)$, and $v' = (1,1)$. Then we have 
$$ U = {\rm span}\{v', F(v')\} = {\rm span}\{(1,1), (1,-1)\} = \mathbf R^2 $$
But $\R^2 = \R\cdot (1,0) \oplus \R\cdot (0,1)$ and both $\R \cdot (1,0)$ and $\R \cdot (0,1)$ are $F$-invariant, as $F(0,1) =(0,-1)$, $F(1,0) = (1,0)$.